# JOLT Transform : Extract and combine fields from multiple JSON arrays to single array output, where one of the arrays can also be null

Tags: json, transform, apache-nifi, jolt

I had asked a question previously:
[JOLT Transform : Extract and combine fields from multiple JSON arrays to single array output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73487310/jolt-transform-extract-and-combine-fields-from-multiple-json-arrays-to-single)

This is a bit different question, where the arrays can actually consist *null* values.

**Example 1:**

```
{
  "questionResponses": [
    {
      "responses": null
    }
  ],
  "answers": [
    {
      "questionId": "1",
      "answerId": "answer 1"
    },
    {
      "questionId": "1",
      "answerId": "answer 2"
    }
  ],
  "totalAttachments": 0
}
```

Undesired Output:

```
null
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "response": null,
    "answerId": "answer 1"
  },
  {
    "response": null,
    "answerId": "answer 2"
  }
]
```

**Example 2:**

```
{
  "questionResponses": [
    {
      "responses": [
        {
          "responseId": "1",
          "response": "response 1"
        },
        {
          "responseId": "2",
          "response": "response 2"
        },
        {
          "responseId": "3",
          "response": "response 3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "answers": null,
  "totalAttachments": 0
}
```

Undesired Output:

```
null
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "response": "response 1",
    "answerId": null
  },
  {
    "response": "response 2",
    "answerId": null
  },
  {
    "response": "response 3",
    "answerId": null
  }
]
```

**JOLT Spec:**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "questionR*": {
        "*": {
          "responses": {
            "*": {
              "@(4,answers)": "@(1,response)"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Determine two independent arrays both with size of 6
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$1": "response",
          "a*": "&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // expand those arrays as objects which contain desired key-value pairs
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&.&1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // get rid of object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

The JOLT Spec works as expected when both of the arrays consists at least single value. But fails when either of them is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **shift** transformations to call `responses` and `questionResponses` individually while referencing one nested in another mutually, in first of them

(`@(4,answers)` nested within `questionResponses`

and

`@(2,questionResponses)` nested within `answers`)

such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "questionR*": {
        "*": {
          "responses": {
            "*": {
              "response": "[&1].&",
              "@(4,answers)": "[&1].answerId"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "answers": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,questionResponses)": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&4.&.[&2]"
            }
          },
          "ans*": {
            "@": "&3.&1[&2]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "answers": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "[&].&2"
          }
        }
      },
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

the demoes on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ :

for **Example 1**:

[image]

for **Example 2**:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Barbaros,
The solution works fine for the second type of example.
For the first example:

Expected output:
```
[
  {
    "responses": null,
    "answerId": "answer 1"
  },
  {
    "responses": null,
    "answerId": "answer 2"
  }
]
```
But the spec provides the undesired output:
```
[
  {
    "responses": null,
    "answerId": "answer 1"
  },
  {
    "responses": null,
    "answerId": "answer 1"
  }
]
```
The first answerId is repeated for the number of responses.
Can you please highlight where the changes can be made?

Comment: let me have a check it out @Vectors

Comment: Hi @Vectors I've just fixed.

Comment: Hi @Barbaros, it's working as expected, now I can use proceed with two flows, one consisting null (this question) and one having at least one value (previous linked question) to get my expected output for a large file consisting such arrays. Thanks for the specification.